# How to handle Oracle synonyms with Flyway 2.0.1?

Tags: sql, oracle, flyway, synonym

I'm using flyway for a long time now. Very nice/complete tool!

I'm actually facing an unexpected situation... I have two schemas:

- An Owner pocessing the tables and sequences
- A User using synonyms to access the Owner objects

The custom does not want me to give the 'grant create any synonym / drop any synonym' rights to the Owner.
But I can provide the 'grant create synonym' to the User.

So I need to

1. Create the tables/sequences (connected with the Owner)
2. Grant Select, Delete... to my User schema (connected with the Owner)
3. Create a synonym for the User to access the Owner objects (connected with the User)

The point 3 is my problem.

If I give the 'grant any synonym' to the owner and using the flyway placeholders, I can do something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ${user}.WORKITEMINFO FOR WORKITEMINFO;
```

BUT I cannot ;)

So the solution I implemented is to use java migrations using another DataSource connected to the User schema. (My MigrationUtils.replacePlaceholders allows me to get access to any of the flyway.properties properties as placeholder)

```
private final static String[] queries =
        {"CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TASK_COMMENT FOR ${flyway.user}.TASK_COMMENT"}

@Override
public void migrate(final Connection connection) throws Exception {

    final DataSource dataSource = MigrationUtils.getUserDataSource();

    final Connection connectionForMigrations = dataSource.getConnection();

    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(connectionForMigrations);
    new TransactionTemplate(connectionForMigrations).execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction() {

            try {
                for (final String query : queries) {
                    final String replacedQuery = MigrationUtils.replacePlaceholders(query);
                    LOG.debug("Executing SQL: " + replacedQuery);
                    jdbcTemplate.executeStatement(replacedQuery);
                }
            } catch (final SQLException exc) {
                throw new FlywayException("Could not drop synonym", exc);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

}
```

Is there another way to resolve this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: And why exactly doesn't the create synonym statement work?

Comment: The create synonym works, but I also need to drop synonyms. The real problem is that my customer does not want me to provide the 'grant drop any synonym' to the Owner.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to qualify the schema name in the application.

If that's not possible and the application uses only SQL (not PL/SQL) to access the "Owner" objects, you could avoid synonyms at all by changing the default schema in an after-logon trigger:

```
create or replace trigger USERX.a_logon_USERX
after logon on USERX
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=standard');
END;
```

However, it's  somewhat hard that to grasp that this technique fails when the application sends PL/SQL blocks ("begin ... end;") to the database. PL/SQL is compiled and therefore cannot consider the current schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dflyway.schemas=OWNER_NAME` while you run flyway.